# Kernel of a homomorphism is subgroup of squares

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\gamma:(\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z})^*\rightarrow \{1,-1\}$ be defined as $\gamma(a)=(\frac{a}{p})$, the Legendre symbol; $p$ is an odd prime, and $m$ is an integer greater or equal to $1$.

I have proved that this is a surjective homomorphism, but I am not sure how to prove that its kernel is exactly the subgroup of squares of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z})^*$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to show that every element $x$ of the subgroup of squares has $(x|p)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

You can deduce this from the fact that he group $({\mathbb Z}/p^m{\mathbb Z})^*$ is the direct product of a cyclic group of order $p-1$ generated by a generator $z$ of $({\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z})^*$, and a cyclic group of order $p^{n-1}$ generated by $1+p$. Since $1+p$ has odd order, it is a square in $({\mathbb Z}/p^m{\mathbb Z})^*$

So, for an element $x = z^i(1+p)^j$ of $({\mathbb Z}/p^m{\mathbb Z})^*$, we have $x \equiv z^i \mod p$, so  $\gamma(x) = \left(\frac{z^i}{p}\right)$  which is $1$ iff $i$ is even iff $x$ is a square.

Comment: Isn't $({\mathbb Z}/p^m{\mathbb Z})^*$ cyclic for odd prime $p$?

Comment: Yes that's right. A direct product of two cyclic groups of coprime order is cyclic.